# Build in error in MainActivity.java file

Tags: android

```
package com.example.buttontest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void doSomething(View v) {
        Log.d("Krishna","button was clicked");
    }
}
```

when i am writing the method
`public void doSomething(View v) {  Log.d("Krishna","button was clicked");  }`

In the above method 2 errors are coming

1. View cannot be resolved to a type
2. Log cannot be resolved.

Please tell how to resolve this build error

Comment: import android.util.Log;

Comment: use `SHIFT+CTRL+O` to import all required packages if you are using Eclipse IDE

Comment: And clean your project

Comment: import android.view.View

Comment: If you're on eclipse, this hotkey is handy:
Mac: command-shift-o
Win: ctr-shift-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one this just click the following keys

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

It will automatically import the usefull class or package and

automatically remove use less import

or simply for this specific problem

you can follow @codeMagic's answer; by manually adding the imports

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `import`s

```
import android.view.View;
import android.util.Log;
```